# What's the order of defer and named return value

Tags: go

Look at these two blocks of code:

```
// return 0
func f() int {
    res := 0 
    defer func(){
        res++
    }()
    return res
}
```

I know that the defer expression is executed after the return expression.
But why is it different when there's a named return value?
Why doesn't the following function return a `0`?

```
// return 1
func f() (res int) {
    res = 0 
    defer func(){
        res++
    }()
    return res
}
```

Comment: See [gopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69818604/1256452) for the logic behind it, but the short version is: only *named* return variables can be modified in a deferred call.

Answer (score 5):

The order of execution is:

1. The return statement sets result parameters.
2. Deferred calls execute.
3. The function returns the result parameters.

A deferred function can modify named result parameters before the function returns.

The deferred function in the first example modifies the local variable `res`, not the unnamed result parameter. The function `f` returns 0 because `return` sets the result parameter to 0 and the deferred function does not change the result parameter.

The second function returns 1 because the deferred function modifies the result parameter `res`.

Comment: In the first function, it makes a temporary variable and give the value of `res` to it. Then we only change the value of original `res`. And then return the temporary variable. Do you mean that?